# Flutter Bloc Rx dart combineLatest2 combine function not running

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, rxdart

I'm writing a flutter app and and using the bloc library. I have a bloc and a cubit, within the state of each is a list of ids of some other documents I need to fetch from firestore. There can be some overlap and some docs are already fetched so I want to get the list of ids from both states, compare them, and then only go to firestore for ones that exist in one but no the other.

I set a new cubit for this:

```
class CircleRecipesCubit extends Cubit<CircleRecipesState> {
  CircleRecipesCubit({
    @required RecipesBloc recipesBloc,
    @required CirclesCubit circlesCubit,
  })  : assert(
          recipesBloc != null,
          circlesCubit != null,
        ),
        _recipesBloc = recipesBloc,
        _circlesCubit = circlesCubit,
        super(CircleRecipesInitial());

  final RecipesBloc _recipesBloc;
  final CirclesCubit _circlesCubit;

  StreamSubscription _recipesSubscription;
  StreamSubscription _circlesSubscription;

  Future<void> getCircleRecipes() async {
    // get a list of recipes the user already has loaded
    List<String> userRecipesIds;
    _recipesSubscription = _recipesBloc.stream.listen((RecipesState event) {
      if (event is RecipesLoaded) {
        userRecipesIds = event.recipes.map((e) => e.id).toList();
        print('*');
        print(userRecipesIds);
        print('*');
      }
    });

    // get a list of recipes in the circles
    List<String> circleRecipeIds;
    _circlesSubscription = _circlesCubit.stream.listen((CirclesState event) {
      if (event is CirclesLoaded) {
        circleRecipeIds = event.circles.fold([],
            (previousValue, element) => [...previousValue, ...element.recipes]);

        print('|');
        print(circleRecipeIds);
        print('|');
        // List<String> circleOnlyRecipeIds = circleRecipeIds;
        // circleRecipeIds.removeWhere((e) => userRecipesIds.contains(e));
        // print(circleOnlyRecipeIds);
      }
    });

    // reduce the list of recipes to a set of only circle recipes
    //TODO

    //------- Try with RX dart

    Stream<RecipesState> recipesStream = _recipesBloc.stream;
    Stream<CirclesState> circlesStream = _circlesCubit.stream;
    Rx.combineLatest2(recipesStream, circlesStream, (
      RecipesState recipesState,
      CirclesState circlesState,
    ) {
      print("This doesn't print!");
      print(recipesState);
      print(circlesState);

      if (recipesState is RecipesLoaded) {
        userRecipesIds = recipesState.recipes.map((e) => e.id).toList();
        print('*');
        print(userRecipesIds);
        print('*');
      }
      if (circlesState is CirclesLoaded) {
        circleRecipeIds = circlesState.circles.fold([],
            (previousValue, element) => [...previousValue, ...element.recipes]);

        print('|');
        print(circleRecipeIds);
        print('|');
        // List<String> circleOnlyRecipeIds = circleRecipeIds;
        // circleRecipeIds.removeWhere((e) => userRecipesIds.contains(e));
        // print(circleOnlyRecipeIds);

      }
      // fetch the set of recipes
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _recipesSubscription.cancel();
    _circlesSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

So above is my cubit - it listens to the recipesBloc and the circlesCubit. The first two expressions in the `getCiricleRecipes()` function are only there to prove that its hooked up correctly - when it runs those print statement print the ids I want it to from both the other bloc and the other cubit.

I need the latest values from both though at the same time to compare them - so I thought rx.combinelatest2 would be good. I give it the stream from the bloc and the cubit. But the combiner function doesn't even run even though things seem 'wired up' correctly.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both streams have already emitted at least one item.

[`combineLatest` documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx/combineLatest2.html) states:

> The Stream will not emit until all streams have emitted at least one item.

Since the first block (where you subscribe to `_circlesCubit`) prints, then most likely `_recipesBloc` is the culprit here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still not there though - actually both both of those print statements work OK and print what I expect though.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't subscribe fast enough then? `Cubit`'s stream is a `BroadcastStream` which is a hot stream, meaning it will emit items without waiting for any subscribers.